# React page is not rendering after import authentication firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication, react-router

I'm working on Register page for user authentication with firebse. Everything is ok until I import `auth` from firebase. after import everything it successfully compile but in the local Host the page is not rendering.

> firebase version: 9.8.2 ,
> react version: 18.1.0

I could not able to find the problem.
here is my code,
**Firebase.js**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {getAuth} from 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';



const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyDjik3vamMzadsohPIgmg6wCfvVOsPXwqQ",
authDomain: "clone-4a714.firebaseapp.com",
projectId: "clone-4a714",
storageBucket: "clone-4a714.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "874031753512",
appId: "1:874031753512:web:c9bf76d4896352ed5ec81d",
measurementId: "G-4762P014BR"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export  const db = app.firestore();
export  const auth = getAuth(app);
```

**Register.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import "./register.css"
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"
import { auth } from '../../firebase';

const Register = () => {
const history = useNavigate();
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [Password, setPassword] = useState('');

const register = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, Password)
        .then((auth) => {
            console.log(auth);
            history('/');
        })
        .catch(error => alert(error.message))

  };

   return (
    <div className='register'>
        <Link to="/">
            <img className='register__logo' src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/amazon/amazon_PNG21.png" alt="" />
        </Link>
        <div className="register__container">

            <h1>Create Account</h1>
            <form >

                <h5>Your name</h5>

                <input type="text" placeholder="First and last name" />


                <h5>Mobile number</h5>
                <div className="mobileNumber">
                    <select className='option'>
                        <option>IN +91</option>
                    </select>

                    <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile number" />

                </div>

                <h5>Email</h5>

                <input type="text" placeholder="Email" Value={email} onClick={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />

                <h5>Password</h5>

                <input type="text" placeholder="Atleast 6 numbers" Value={Password} onClick={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />

                <button className='register__button' type='submit' onClick={register}>
                    <h5>Continue</h5>
                </button>
                <div className="detail">
                    <p>Already have an account?</p>
                    <Link to="/login" className='signIn'>
                        <p>Sign in</p>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

  export default Register
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header/header.jsx';
import Home from './components/Home/home.jsx';
import Checkout from './components/checkout/checkout.jsx';
import Login from './components/Login/login.jsx';
 import Register from './components/Register/register';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
 return (
//BEM 
 <Router>
    <div className="app">
      <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<><Header/><Home/> </>}/>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
      <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>}/>
      <Route path="/checkout" element={<><Header/><Checkout/></>}/>
      </Routes>
    </div>
   </Router>
  );
 }

 export default App;
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail *other than* "it's not working"? Are there any errors in the console? Is *anything* rendering, like the `Header` and `Home` components on the `"/"` path? What are the steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @DrewReese actually every component is rendering before import the {auth} in Register.jsx . after importing the firebase in Register , nothing is rendering, only white page is showing up. There is no error is console, it successfully compiled.

Comment: Is it only the `"/register"` route/ `Register` component that has issue rendering? Do the other routes render without issue? Are there any logs, any other details?

Comment: no, the other routes are not rendering as well. But when I remove the `import { auth } from '../../firebase';` from Register , then all routes are rendering.

Comment: @DrewReese  The issue is showing after importing the `{ auth }` . Can't understand where I messing up.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint/console.log the `auth` object before it's exported what is that value? If you breakpoint/log it in `Register` where it's imported, what is the value there?

Comment: @DrewReese I didn't get that. What value u asking for?

Comment: `const auth = getAuth(app);` - what is the value of `auth`, and `import { auth } from '../../firebase';` - what is the value of `auth`?

Comment: I initialize **app** so I can use Firebase throughout the app. And this will use our config to recognize the project and initialize authentication modules from firebase.